# what does following path means "/^\/.*/" in get function of Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to programming and have been reading Node.js code.

I don't understand what does the path `/^\/.*$/` means in the following function.

```
  app.get(/^\/.*$/, function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + indexPath)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) which matches the character `/` and any other, or no characters following it. In short, it will catch all request paths.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a great tool for building and deciphering regexes, I recommend you take a look.

Good luck!